# Unity C# Simple Multiplayer game ending

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I edit the c# code to show that player 1 or 2 won when the other player dies. And show the dead player that they lost?

PlayerController Script

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.Networking;

namespace S3
{
public class PlayerController : NetworkBehaviour {

    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public Transform bulletSpawn;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    if (!isLocalPlayer) {
        return;
    }

    float x = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 150.0f;
    float z = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 3.0f;

    transform.Rotate (0, x, 0);
    transform.Translate (0, 0, z);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) 
        {
            CmdFire();
        }
}

    [Command]
    void CmdFire()
    {
        GameObject bullet = (GameObject) Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletSpawn.position, bulletSpawn.rotation);

        bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity = bullet.transform.forward * 6.0f;

        NetworkServer.Spawn(bullet);

        Destroy (bullet, 2);
    }

    public override void OnStartLocalPlayer()
        {
    GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.color = Color.blue;
    }


}
}
```

Health Script

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

namespace S3
{
    public class Health : NetworkBehaviour {

        public const int maxHealth = 100;
        [SyncVar (hook =  "OnChangeHealth")]public int currentHealth = maxHealth;
        public RectTransform healthbar;

        public void TakeDamage(int amount)
        {
        if (!isServer) 
        {
            return;
        }

        currentHealth -= amount;
        if (currentHealth <= 0) 
        {
            currentHealth = maxHealth;
            RpcRespawn();
        }
    }

    void OnChangeHealth(int health)
    {
        healthbar.sizeDelta = new Vector2(health * 2, healthbar.sizeDelta.y);
    }


    [ClientRpc]
    void RpcRespawn()
    {
        if(isLocalPlayer)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.zero;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

This is the codeaspğlasdlişsadlşisadlşiadsilşdslaişdlasişlişdsacdl işsadilşaLDİŞaslişÖDASİÖŞLDÖİLSAŞDöliasödilascöildaiölşsdöiaşsdöilasödilasiöldasöildasöildöilasdöilaöildöildasöildaöilsdöilasdölasdöliasölidasöildsaöildsöiladiösladöilsadöilsadöilasdiölsadiölsaöidlsaöildsöidiösladiölsadiölsadöilasöild

Comment: what does sted og picture mean

Comment: They mean "instead of". You should just post the code instead of links to images.

Comment: thats all i can do

Comment: Have you tried any solutions yourself? You should replace the excess characters from the end with a more detailed explanation of what you have tried and what you're trying to achieve. Have you read the [Multiplayer and Networking section](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNet.html) of the Unity manual?

Answer (score 0):

You can send a Command to the server with netID of the player who have won and check in RPC if the netID matches.
If netID matches for the local player then, he is the winner. Otherwise, he loses. Haven't tested the code below but should work:

```
   [Command]
    public void CmdGameWon()
    {
        RpcGameEnd(this.netId);
    }

   [ClientRpc]
    public void RpcGameEnd(NetworkInstanceId nid)
    {
        if(this.isLocalPlayer && this.netId==nid){
            //Process win here
        }else{
            //Process lose here
        }
    }
```